# Shadow casting in 2D OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 2d, mathematics, lighting, shadows

I´ve read several articles, tutorials about shadow casting and I think that I understand the way how it works. However I miss some of the steps. Here is included my order list:

1. Fill framebuffer with ambient light
2. Render light textures to the framebuffer(adding proper blending)

**3. Lights have vector of shadow casters(convex polygons) and check if they touch them(by checking the distance) and if yes, I do proper math calculation to project the polygon to the right "transformation". Then I draw them as black polygons to the framebuffer**

4.At the end I use this framebuffers texture and blend it with actual game textures to "do lighting (with shadows)".

As you can see I bolded the step 3 because thats where I´m lost. The first thing, how do I project the polygon? (for these polygons I have a vector of points, also a vector of edges). The second thing, is it efficient to do it this way? I mean to iterate through the possible shadow casters for each light.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your last question, yes, you have to iterate through every caster, in same cases even multiple times. I've just made a simple game based on shadow and light ( https://youtu.be/fNp7GeHxInI ).
Of course it depends on your game, but I think that with 2d games it's better to draw the light, not the shadow (in this way you can blend together different lights, if you render the shadows you can't in a easy way: when you draw a shadow you can't light that area anymore now that's black (there are of course tricks to avoid this problem)).
In my game I use a lot of shadow casters so, if I projected shadows a lot of them would overlapped and that's not very efficient since you're GPU has to redraw the same pixels different times. Anyway to project shadows you need the light vectors that goes to the center of your point light to each vertex of each caster, then you lengthen them till the end of your "light box" (the square which contains the light texture) or to a fixed value based on the height of the caster if the light is in an higher position. Now you have the vertices you need to draw the shadow: the polygon vertices and the end of each light vector. You draw the light and then its shadows.
That's has a complexity of O(n*k) where n are the lights and k the casters.

If you wanna render lights the algorithm it's more difficult, basically you take the light center and the polygons' vertices to draw the light triangles, but you have to calculate which is the nearest wall (the one to be enlightened). That's has a complexity of O(n*k²) but I think you can optimize it to something like O(n*log(k)). 
This way reduces the calculations done by the GPU (you only render the light pixels once and you don't even render the shadowed areas, before you render both and the shadows even multiple times), remember that the casters in a scene would be at most an hundred or similar while the pixel of a monitor are millions, so k² (the worst case) in this scenario is better than k if you will draw a lot less pixels.

For any question ask in comments. I've not been so specific because there are already a lot of tutorials online. (I can link them if you need).

Comment: What do you mean by drawing the light, not the shadow? According to this tutorial (http://fisherevans.com/blog/post/2d-lighting-and-shadows) I thought that I´m rendering the shadows as well. Btw nice video!

Comment: @Pins like this: http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/

Comment: So basically, when we talk about OpenGL, i pass a vector of shadow casters to a light, it checks its vertices if they are front face or not, then lengthen them and render the light texture as triangle fan using all vertices? (I have to also calculate the UV for the vertices used for triangle fan and also care about the order)

Comment: And also at the start I have 4 vertices, and check all vertices I will have with a center of the light.

Comment: You have to check if the light ray hits that vertex or if it is blocked by a wall. (That's causes the O(n²) complexity: for each vertex you have to check every wall). Here there's same code: http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/

Comment: You can always go with the "project shadow method", it's simpler and you won't see any performance hit I think. Anyway I can post more specific code if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62695/discussion-between-pins-and-liuka).

Comment: Looks interesting. @Liuka can u share code of your youtube example? I am working on top down 2d rpg and wanna add lightings and shadows like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KvjEiur0eY. But no success yet

Comment: Yeah, sure, wait a moment. Maybe give me credit if you use it.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vRleCILF5PhqAMy1VVpnYWm_6EZQQjzz

Comment: The code it's quite a mess, basically I create a square mesh for each light and remove like with a "swiping ray" every object inside it, projecting its shadow to the border of the square. If I remember correctly It's optimized to work only with AABB casters, but I think you can easily change that (removing some assumption from the code about the aligment of the segments). It DOES NOT WORK with overlapped geometry (you can still overlap the boredrs tough). Hope I've said everything about the code, I dont remember it much :) Ask for everything.

Comment: Thanks for code and quick response. I examined it,but have a question.

Is that a right use with custom static shapes like trees,building and etc. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV4mi0tI1cY)?
Cuz i see only rectangle shadow.

Comment: Nope, it works only with AABB rects, but if I remember correctly, it can easily be changed to works with every type of 2D geometry since the algorithm works on wall units, not rectangle ones.

Comment: I see. But maybe you give advice or references how to build shadow projection for tree,leaves and etc. http://streak.club/img/dXBsb2Fkcy9pbWFnZS8zODgxLmpwZw==/600x/oOjkcd.jpg.

Comment: Since in all the images/videos you've shown shadows are pixel perfect (they are based on the texture and not on the mesh) I think they are done through some kind of readapted 3d shadow map technique, which is really different of what is described in this question/answers. Try googling shadow mapping and see some tutorial.